# Laravel 5.8 - How to Retrieve specific Notificaitions from Laravel Notifications

Tags: laravel, notifications

I have created 2 notifications - `DataBase Hosted`...

1. one is for letting user know about the status of their requests from admin which is named `ListingsNotifications`
2. When customer send user a message to user named `NotifyUser`

now in user dashboard section, i want to display notifications only by `NotifyUser` class and not from `ListingsNotifications`

The code for retrieving notifications is, which doesn't suits in my case

> @foreach($messages->readNotifications as $message)
>
> @endforeach

how can i do this..

Comment: There are different types of notifications in Laravel. You need to describe the technology which I suspect is Database hosted. If that is the case you can find the table and write an eloquent query to get a specific row.

Comment: yes thats Database hosted

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know your table structure I will write a general query, tune it as you wish, and don't forget to import DB facade.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

and the query:

```
DB::table('notifications')
    ->where('notifiable_type', 'App\User')
    ->where('notifiable_id', $user->id)
    ->get();
```

Please investigate your database to see what query conditions you need to add. This query will get all the notifications issued to a single user, regardless of the source it came from.